# IsNullOrEmpty and IsNullOrWhiteSpace return "System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText"

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
        protected void btnAddAppliance(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var description = "";
            var succeeded = true;

            try
            {
                description = Convert.ToString(iptDescription);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(description) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(description))
                {
                    errormessage.Text = "You need to add a description!";
                    errormessage.Visible = true;
                    succeeded = false;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                errormessage.Text = "Enter a correct description!";
                errormessage.Visible = true;
                succeeded = false;
            }

            if (succeeded)
            {
                _c.NewAppliance(description);
                grvAppliances.DataSource = _c.GetAllAppliances();
                grvAppliances.DataBind();
                iptDescription.Value = "";
            }
        }
```

Hello, I have a problem with my code. This code checks if the valuables I entered are not null or do not contain any spaces using the `IsNullOrEmpty()` and `IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` methods. Everytime I leave my inputs blank, it returns `"System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText"` and puts it in my MySQL Database instead prompting me with the errormessage I made. How can I fix this?

Comment: Thank you, it works!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Value` property of the html control element as already suggested in comment. So instead of saying `Convert.ToString(iptDescription)` you should use `Convert.ToString(iptDescription.Value)`

Moreover, `ToString()` unless overridden returns the fully qualified name of the type .. in your case the the HTML control element `HtmlInputText`

Comment: The value property is already a string, and those controls will never return `null` from a `Value` or `Text` property, so you don't have to bother calling `Convert.ToString`. Keep your code simple and clear.